# Paquage or other way for IRC or other chat system rendering

Tags: packages, rendering, dialogue

I know that [`dramatist`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/dramatist?lang=en) exist but it is made to get theater rendering.

However I need to get chat representations with all chat specificities and usage like events managing (someone left, someone enter, someone is kicked), time, ect… It would be great if this package could support at least IRC and XMPP features.

Edit: I don’t search way to get computer or phone interface rendering but real typographic text with paragraphs, break line, ect…

So, there is a package or a way to get this feature from LaTeX?

Comment: I'm pretty sure no such package exists, and you'll have to do the typesetting yourself (and then you can upload your package to CTAN for others to use). Should be fun!

Comment: This has been answered before: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/239511/10995

Comment: @HenriMenke, I am sorry but this answer show a verry specific case and only give an Android rendering. However I try to get real typographied text rendering. Furthermore, this `kik-android` don’t manage IRC or XMPP behavior. `kik-android` don’t answer at all my question.